# How to get rewritten url

Tags: java, spring

When I deploy my app (.war) at tomcat I get directory in webapps named like 'myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
this app I redirect by AJP

server.xml (partial)

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" address="::1" port="8009"
       redirectPort="8443" secretRequired="false" />
```

in Httpd apache I use the following code
httpd.conf (partial)

```
<Location /myapp>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/myapp-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
</Location>
```

For creating download url in my app I'm using

```
final String baseUrl =
        ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().build().toUriString();
```

when I start app on test I get url like

for web `http://192.168.10.1.85/`

for downloading `http://192.168.10.1:85/files/PRN1/001234/firmware/file.zip` (this link generated based on data from database and it is dynamically)

Ok. it's good I see all correctly.

When I open httpd link in web
`http://192.168.10.1/myapp` - ok it's correct

but for my dynamic link I get incorrect context path
`http://192.168.10.1/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/files/PRN1/001234/firmware/file.zip` - it's not correct and my app couldn't provide data from this link

good link `http://192.168.10.1/myapp/files/PRN1/001234/firmware/file.zip`

How to correct describe baseUrl?
Or I should add data about Location some in configuration?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, from Database "files/PRN1/001234/firmware/file.zip" this path generated dynamically and then you combine your web application's address with this
path.

Then you can use below url generation method in java

```
  String protocol = "http";
    String host = "192.168.10.1";
    int port = 8080;
    String path = "/myapp/files/PRN1/001234/firmware/file.zip";
    String auth = null;
    String fragment = null;
    URI uri = new URI(protocol, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment);
    URL url = uri.toURL();
```

Comment: At test, I have link `http://192.168.10.1:82/...`. Project was deploy on tomcat and really link is `http://192.168.10.1/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/`, but I use redirect from httpd `http://192.168.10.1/myapp`. May I get link `http://192.168.10.1/myapp` via ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()? I should get httpd link but not deploy